# Apply strsplit and ifelse condition accross multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, sapply, strsplit

I have a dataframe as shown below and the output from this code is shown below.

- Essentially, I want to read values from columns which can be of two formats as shown in col1 and col2.
- If the format is as in col1 then we split text and read third element and if the format is as in col2 we read the cell value as it is.
- We then want to pass condition if the values in columns (col1 and col3 after splitting col1) to create col4 and col5.
- Finally, we want the result in col6.
- the variable "selection" is a list of numbers

Question: Since in the original dataframe, there can be multiple columns of value format type as in col1 and col2, how the code below can be modified to get the desired output?

```
#STEP1

df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("abc_1_102", "abc_1_103", "xyz_1_104"),
  col2 = c("107", "108", "106")
)

#STEP2

split_text <- strsplit(df$col1, "_")

third_elements <- sapply(split_text, function(x) if(length(x) >= 3) x[3] else NA)

#STEP3

df$col3<-third_elements

#STEP4

selection<-c(107,102,108)

df$col4<-ifelse(df$col2 %in% selection,"SELECT","NOTSELECT")

df$col5<-ifelse(df$col3 %in% selection,"SELECT","NOTSELECT")

#STEP5

df$col6<-paste(df$col4,df$col5,sep = ",")
```

Output from above code:

```
       col1 col2 col3      col4      col5                col6
1 abc_1_102  107  102    SELECT    SELECT       SELECT,SELECT
2 abc_1_103  108  103    SELECT NOTSELECT    SELECT,NOTSELECT
3 xyz_1_104  106  104 NOTSELECT NOTSELECT NOTSELECT,NOTSELECT
```

Desired output

```
       col1 col2                col6
1 abc_1_102  107       SELECT,SELECT
2 abc_1_103  108    NOTSELECT,SELECT
3 xyz_1_104  106 NOTSELECT,NOTSELECT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this all in one go with by pasting two `ifelse` statements together. The `ifelse` for `col2` is straightforward. The `ifelse` for `col3` uses `grepl` to search for any of the numbers in `select` by creating a search string using `paste(..., collapse = "|")` (pasting the "or" operator between them). The outer `paste(..., sep = ",")` puts it all together:

```
df$col6 <- paste(ifelse(df$col2 %in% selection, "SELECT", "NOTSELECT"),
                 ifelse(grepl(paste(selection, collapse = "|"), df$col1), "SELECT", "NOTSELECT"),
                 sep = ",")
```

Or to more safely add a word boundary to the second `ifelse` (thanks to @r2evans!)

```
df$col6 <- paste(ifelse(df$col2 %in% selection, "SELECT", "NOTSELECT"),
                 ifelse(grepl(
                   paste0("(^|_)(", paste(selection, collapse = "|"), ")(_|$)\\b"), 
                   df$col1),
                   "SELECT", "NOTSELECT"),
                 sep = ",")
```

Both give the same output in this example:

```
       col1 col2                col6
1 abc_1_102  107       SELECT,SELECT
2 abc_1_103  108    SELECT,NOTSELECT
3 xyz_1_104  106 NOTSELECT,NOTSELECT
```

Comment: @vp_050 I'm a bit unclear on what you mean - is `selection` actually a matrix or data frame with multiple columns? Could you edit your question to reflect this scenario? I'll be happy to update my answer

Comment: You know @vp_050, when you _change your expected output_, you cannot expected everybody's already-submitted answers to have foreseen your reversal. The order of the results are completely user-controlled, though, by changing the order of the two `ifelse` (as well in my answer).

Comment: Also, I changed the desired output table. This was a mistake from my side. Also, if there is blank cell in col1 and col2 the code returns "select" or "notselect" randomly.

Comment: @r2evans that's it! thank you for the help - I have updated the answer to reflect the improved code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```r
df$col6 <- paste(
  ifelse(df$col2 %in% selection, "SELECT", "NOTSELECT"),
  strsplit(df$col1, "_") |>
    sapply(`%in%`, selection) |>
    colSums() |>
    ifelse("SELECT", "NOTSELECT"),
  sep = ",")
#        col1 col2                col6
# 1 abc_1_102  107       SELECT,SELECT
# 2 abc_1_103  108    SELECT,NOTSELECT
# 3 xyz_1_104  106 NOTSELECT,NOTSELECT
```